# Getting a js error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling

im getting this error in chrome browser:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined,can somebody help with this code issue?
I think the error its because of this line: if (!text.trim()){...}.., but dont know how to fix it.

-JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $inputs = $('.resizing-input');

    // Resize based on text if text.length > 0
    // Otherwise resize based on the placeholder
    function resizeForText(text) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!text.trim()) {
            text = $this.attr('placeholder').trim();
        }
        var $span = $this.parent().find('span');
        $span.text(text);
        var $inputSize = $span.width();
        $this.css("width", $inputSize);
    }
    $inputs.find('input').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which && e.charCode) {
            var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode | e.charCode);
            var $this = $(this);
            resizeForText.call($this, $this.val() + c);
        }
    });
    $inputs.find('input').keydown(function (e) { if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) { var arr = $(this).val().split(""); arr.splice((arr.length)-1,1); resizeForText.call($(this), arr.join("")); } });

    $inputs.find('input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        resizeForText.call($this, $this.val())
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, the error means that `text` or `$this.attr('placeholder')` is `undefined`. Make sure you are not passing `undefined` to `resizeForText` and make sure that `$this` has an attribute `placeholder` . Debug your code: Set a breakpoint and step through it step by step.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode | e.charCode)` should use `||` instead of `|`. You need boolean logic, not bit-wise logic here.